# PostgreSQL - How can I return results from multiple field IDs?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to rewrite this query so I can return results from four field IDs:  industry, location, phone number, SFDC contact ID.

At the bottom,  you will see I commented out the other columns I would like to surface.  Due to the way this is currently written, I can only show one at a time, and have to uncomment/comment accordingly.  An important consideration is to write this so it shows all records available for industry, or location, or phone number, or SFDC contact ID (as opposed to only show records where data is available across the board through an implied "and").

As a bonus, the phone number value does include the type.  Any way to remove that?  For example: "123-456-7890|work" ...I would just want this to be "123-456-7890" but worst case, I can always remove this in Excel.

I appreciate any help with this.

```
select cmsuser.userid as "User ID", 
cmsuser.username as "Username", 
cmsuser.firstname as "First Name", 
cmsuser.lastname as "Last Name", 
cmsuser.email as "Email", 
cmsuser.userenabled as "Enabled?",
to_char(date(to_timestamp(cmsuser.creationdate/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Creation Date",
to_char(date(to_timestamp(cmsuser.modificationdate/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Modification Date", 
to_char(date(to_timestamp(cmsuser.lastloggedin/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Last Logged In", 
to_char(date(to_timestamp(cmsuser.lastprofileupdate/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Last Profile Update",
---****** Industry ******
cmsuserprofile.value as "Industry"
from cmsuser, cmsuserprofile 
where cmsuser.userid = cmsuserprofile.userid and cmsuserprofile.fieldid = '5011' and cmsuser.userenabled = '1';
---****** Location ******
---cmsuserprofile.value as "Location"
---from cmsuser, cmsuserprofile 
---where cmsuser.userid = cmsuserprofile.userid and cmsuserprofile.fieldid = '6' and cmsuser.userenabled = '1';
---****** Phone Number ******
---cmsuserprofile.value as "Phone Number"
---from cmsuser, cmsuserprofile 
---where cmsuser.userid = cmsuserprofile.userid and cmsuserprofile.fieldid = '1' and cmsuser.userenabled = '1';
---****** SFDC Contact ID ******
---cmsuserprofile.value as "SFDC Contact ID"
---from cmsuser, cmsuserprofile 
---where cmsuser.userid = cmsuserprofile.userid and fieldid = '5004' and cmsuser.userenabled = '1';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  u.userid as "User ID", 
  u.username as "Username", 
  u.firstname as "First Name", 
  u.lastname as "Last Name", 
  u.email as "Email", 
  u.userenabled as "Enabled?",
  to_char(date(to_timestamp(u.creationdate/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Creation Date",
  to_char(date(to_timestamp(u.modificationdate/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Modification Date", 
  to_char(date(to_timestamp(u.lastloggedin/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Last Logged In", 
  to_char(date(to_timestamp(u.lastprofileupdate/1000)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as "Last Profile Update",
  (select p.value from cmsuserprofile p where u.userid = p.userid and p.fieldid = '5011') as "Industry",
  (select p.value from cmsuserprofile p where u.userid = p.userid and p.fieldid = '6') as "Location",
  (select p.value from cmsuserprofile p where u.userid = p.userid and p.fieldid = '1') as "Phone Number",
  (select p.value from cmsuserprofile p where u.userid = p.userid and p.fieldid = '5004') as "SFDC Contact ID"
from cmsuser u where u.userenabled = '1';
```